# Make images that have different heights scale within a container

Tags: html, css, image

I have three images that rest in a container. Two of the images share the same height, while the other one is slightly taller. As a user resizes the screen, how can I have all three images maintain their current ratio while scaling down?

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper-inner panel centered green'>
<section class='content'>
  <article class='full'>
    <h2>Title of section four.</h2>
    <div class="phone-container">

      <img src='http://placehold.it/276x490' class="phone-1 desktop" style="border: 1px solid blue;" />
      <img src='http://placehold.it/320x516' class="phone-2" style="border: 1px solid red;" />
      <img src='http://placehold.it/276x490'class="phone-3 desktop" style="border: 1px solid blue;" />

    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .phone-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .phone-container img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 320px !important;
  }
  .phone-container .phone-1 {
    width: 276px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 0);
    transform: translate(50px, 0);
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
  }
  .phone-container .phone-3 {
    width: 276px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50px, 0);
    transform: translate(-50px, 0);
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
  }
  .phone-container .phone-2 {
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
  }
  .centered {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

From my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3140e2g4/) you can see that I have the images displayed inline with each other having the two outer images underlapping the middle image. This is the positioning I want to maintain when the browser window gets smaller until mobile queries kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use percent width could be a solution ?

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/3140e2g4/3/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 968px) {
  .phone-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .phone-container img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 30% !important;
  }
  .phone-container .phone-1 {
    width: 20%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 0);
    transform: translate(50px, 0);
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
  }
  .phone-container .phone-3 {
    width: 20%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50px, 0);
    transform: translate(-50px, 0);
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
  }
  .phone-container .phone-2 {
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
  }
  .centered {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. As you would resize the screen in your example, the images break their alignment still.

Comment: I can change media query to make it works better. Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/3140e2g4/3/

Comment: Thanks! Although, I'd rather not have it rely on media queries, but rather based off of percentages. The reason for that is I have the design breaking at 768px, and then that's what gets rid of two images.

Comment: Yeah! What did you tweak specifically?

Comment: So when I apply the max-width percentages with my images they seem to continue breaking. Applying 30% to the max-width solves the problem, but it messes up the initial sizing of the images. Doing 40% gets the size right but won't scale.

Comment: I just removed the media query in the end who was applying to these elements and add fluid width like I show you before. (`20% 20% and 23%`), you can remove the `max-width`, it doesn't matter :)